# Why can't windows recovery see the backup that I JUST CREATED?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016

So I'm having some issues installing Windows Server 2016 in that promoting it to a domain controller will cause the server to get caught in a loop of bsod>restart>bsod>restart, etc.

So on the second time around, I created a backup by adding the backup role and creating a one time backup of the system drive. It is located at I:\WindowsImageBackup. I: is not a system drive, it's just a storage drive.

Now I tried applying all updates before enable the AD DS role, but when I enabled it, it bsod'd again. It won't boot. All articles trying to solve this fail. So now I'm trying to restore the image that I successfully created. I booted from the install disc (a usb stick, actually), and went through to the restore from system image. The wizard claims that it cannot find an image. It won't let me back out of that wizard, so I restarted again and brought up the command prompt. I can change directory to I: and I can see the backup.

I run `wbadmin get versions -backupTarget:i`

and it responds by saying it couldn't find the backup or the backup is unsupported.

I'm at my wits end. Can someone shed some light on this? I don't want to spend the next several hours getting the server reinstalled yet again. I'm fairly certain it is the same restore paradigm as other versions of windows, so I'm tagging that as well.

Comment: Promoting a server to domain controller should be your main concern here, why on earth it'll go BSOD in the first place? this is very strange. I'd recommend you use a different install media, your backup could be corrupted for all we know by the same reason your server keeps on BSODing.

Comment: I redid the install without it and I'll go through this again in a VM when I find some time. Maybe I can get some more info without bricking my server :/. The install media is straight off of MSDN